# How to configure linking so that compiled binary finds libraries?

Tags: linux, compilation, ffmpeg, makefile

I'm compiling `ffmpeg`. Configuration:

`--prefix=/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/ffmpeg-build
  --extra-cflags='-I/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/x264-build/include
  -I/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/ogg-build/include
  -I/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/theora-build/include
  -I/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/lame-build/include
  -I/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/faac-build/include
  -I/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/faad-build/include
  -I/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/vpx-build/include
  -I/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/vorbis-build/include
  -I/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/ffmpeg-build/include'
  --extra-ldflags='-L/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/x264-build/lib
  -L/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/ogg-build/lib
  -L/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/theora-build/lib
  -L/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/lame-build/lib
  -L/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/faac-build/lib
  -L/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/faad-build/lib
  -L/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/vpx-build/lib
  -L/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/vorbis-build/lib
  -L/home/john/zope/engage/zeocluster/ffmpeg/parts/ffmpeg-build/lib'`

The build completes fine, and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./parts/ffmpeg-build/lib:./parts/x264-build/lib ./parts/ffmpeg-build/bin/ffmpeg` runs the binary.

Why is that `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` necessary? Didn't I already tell the compiler to link against these libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using gcc you can use a linker option to specify the preferred path for dynamic linking at run time. You can add several `rpath` options, each like this:

```
gcc ... -Wl,-rpath=<PATH>
```

Comment: Diego, your answer looks good. It looks like I should use `--with-stage1-ldflags="-Wl,-rpath,${buildout:directory}/parts/ffmpeg-build/lib,-rpath,${buildout:directory}/parts/x264-build/lib"` as options to `./configure`. Unfortunately it looks like the version of configure in this package is too old.

Comment: You can tweak the Makefiles then after `configure` is run. Sure, they will be some, but not that many perhaps.

Comment: Turns out the same can be accomplished using the `LDFLAGS` environment variable or other corresponding flags in different `configure` flavours.

Comment: Ah, that's right, you can always call `make LDFLAGS=...`. However, I find it estrange ffmpeg compilation support does not support this `rpath` option out of the box. Anyway, glad you fixed it.